# need details of selected user on select laravel

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel

I have two roles in my Laravel application one is packaging company and other is cutting company.
Cutting Company can place order to packaging company. When Cutting Company Selects a packaging company
on other select I need Address of that company.
Here I Select packaging company

```
 <div class="form-group col-lg-6" id="packaging_company">
           <label style="color: #44484d;">Select Packaging Company <span
                   class="text-danger">*</span></label>
              <select class="form-control kt-selectpicker" required data-live-search="true"
                        name="packaging_company">
                   @foreach ($packaging_company as $company)
                       <option value="{{ $company->id }}">
                               {{ $company->staffs->name }}</option>
                   @endforeach
              </select>
   <span class="text-danger p-1">{{ $errors->first('packaging_company') }}</span>
 </div>
```

on this Select I need weather user wants to select address of that company or some other address from google maps

```
<div class="form-group col-lg-6">
   <label style="color: #44484d;">Fruit delivery destination
       <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
        <select class="form-control kt-selectpicker" data-live-search="true" 
          name="fruit_delivery_location">
                <option> Packaging Company Location </option>
                <option> Other </option>
         </select>
<span class="text-danger p-1">{{ $errors->first('fruit_delivery_location') }}</span>
 </div>
```

My Controller

```
 public function createCutting()
    {
            $packaging_company = PackagingCompany::get();
            return view('web.cutting.working_orders.create', 
             compact('packaging_company'));
              
    }
```

Comment: please paste your controller

Comment: I have pasted my Function...Becuase controller has very complex code